# How to build Etherscan webscraper?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, etherscan

I'm building a webscraper that constantly refreshes a buch of etherscan URL's every 30 seconds and if any new transfers have happened that are not accounted for, it sends me an email notification and a link to the relevant address on etherscan so I can manually check them out.

One of the addresses that I wanted to keep tabs on is here:

https://etherscan.io/token/0xd6a55c63865affd67e2fb9f284f87b7a9e5ff3bd?a=0xd071f6e384cf271282fc37eb40456332307bb8af

What I have done so far:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
url = 'https://etherscan.io/token/0xd6a55c63865affd67e2fb9f284f87b7a9e5ff3bd?a=0x94f52b6520804eced0accad7ccb93c73523af089'
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'XYZ/3.0'})   # I got this line from another post since "uClient = uReq(URL)" and "page_html = uClient.read()" would not work (I beleive that etherscan is attemption to block webscraping or something?)
response = urlopen(req, timeout=20).read()
response_close = urlopen(req, timeout=20).close()
page_soup = soup(response, "html.parser")
Transfers_info_table_1 = page_soup.find("div", {"class": "table-responsive"})
print(Transfers_info_table_1)
```

The interesting thing is, when I run this, I get the following output:

```
<div class="table-responsive" style="visibility:hidden;">
<iframe frameborder="0" id="tokentxnsiframe" scrolling="no" src="" style="width: 100px; height: 600px; min-width: 100%;"></iframe>
</div>
```

I was expecting to get the output for the whole table of transfers. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the table is present inside `iframe`.Copy the `src` value of the iframe and then using request get the content of that url.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://etherscan.io/token/generic-tokentxns2?m=normal&contractAddress=0xd6a55c63865affd67e2fb9f284f87b7a9e5ff3bd&a=0xd071f6e384cf271282fc37eb40456332307bb8af'
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'})   # I got this line from another post since "uClient = uReq(URL)" and "page_html = uClient.read()" would not work (I beleive that etherscan is attemption to block webscraping or something?)
response = urlopen(req, timeout=20).read()
response_close = urlopen(req, timeout=20).close()
page_soup = soup(response, "html.parser")
Transfers_info_table_1 = page_soup.find("table", {"class": "table table-md-text-normal table-hover mb-4"})
df=pd.read_html(str(Transfers_info_table_1))[0]
df.to_csv("TransferTable.csv",index=False)
```

Generated csv.

[image]

Comment: `Transfers_info_table_1` appears to be empty now, any ideas why? is etherscan blocking the crawling maybe?